# EF Core single DELETE statement

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following models in a disconnected scenario:

```
public class Module
{
    public Module()
    {
        Students = new List<Student>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        Modules = new List<Module>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Module> Modules { get; set; }
}
```

and I am calling RemoveStudents and pass two student ids below to remove some students from a module

```
public void RemoveStudents(List<long> studentIds)
{
    var module = (from dbModule in dbContext.Module.Include(x => x.Students)
                  select dbModule).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);

    module.Students.RemoveAll(x => studentIds.Contains(x.Id));

    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

I can see the that it generates two delete queries (one for each student).

```
DELETE FROM [ModuleStudent]
WHERE [ModulesId] = @p0 AND [StudentsId] = @p1;
```

For performance reasons in SQL is better to write one query with all the Ids:

```
DELETE FROM [ModuleStudent]
WHERE [ModulesId] = @p0 AND [StudentsId] IN (@p1, @p2, @p3.....);
```

How can I "force" EF to generate delete with multiple params?

Comment: The SaveChanges performs one database round-trip for every entity to delete, but you could do with a sql raw statement, or use something like https://entityframework-extensions.net/bulk-delete

Comment: @alessandro in terms of performance in a large enterprise app with more than 10000 users I think it would be something that can be avoided. The extensions you sent is not free from what I can see. Thanks anyway

Comment: and since I am just deleting an entry from a join table I still dont understand why EF has to check the entire entity. It is a key pair only in the join table.

Comment: the extension is not free, you are right, but for a large enterprise app... all the best ;)